# A Geometry Question utilizing triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In the triangle $ABC\,$ we denote by $O$ and $I$ the circumcenter and incenter respectively. The perpendicular bisectors of the line segments $IA$, $IB$ and $IC$ pairwise intersect thus defining the triangle $A_1B_1C_1$ Prove that $\vec {OI}=\vec {OA_1}+\vec {OB_1}+\vec {OC_1}$

Hi there. Im a high schooler new to olympiad geometry. Ive been unable to solve this problem despite repeated angle chasing could someone give a solution?Note I dont know stuff like projective geometry and hard lemmas so a simple proof would be most appreciated.

Comment: its not solved there.

Comment: But you shouldn't repost the same question.

Comment: @Mojimoji: Yes it is